# Window 7 installation can't detect mouse and keyboard

Tags: windows-7

I just built a brand new pc and was going to install window 7 for it. Before that, my mouse and keyboard works perfectly. However, after the installation is loaded, the computer can't detect the mouse and keyboard (the mouse cursor isn't even showing). I've tried to plug my mouse and keyboard into usb 2.0 port but it doesn't seem to work either.
My spec:
CPU : Ryzen 5 2600
Motherboard : Asrock B450m Pro4-f
Stock logitech mouse and keyboard.

Comment: If the non-working peripherals are wireless, try a wired mouse and keyboard instead. Double-check that the devices are turned on (via any power buttons on the devices) and any batteries are *properly* inserted. Similarly, if they require some special initial "connection" steps, follows those steps. If they came with an installation disk for drivers or special software, make certain that software is installed properly.